# Power of Power to calculate in Java

Tags: java

I have a program to write. The requirement is 1.    Implement code (choose your favorite language) which will calculate the value of 2^(3^(4^(5^6)))

What I have written is this so far ( for 4^(5^6).However, I get 0 as output despite the fact I have even changed the second argument from integer to long.A little help is needed.Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i=4,j=5,k=6;
    System.out.println(pow(i,pow(j,k)));
}

public static long pow(int c, long l){       
    long n=1;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        n=c*n;
    }
    return n;            
}
```

Comment: Debugger to the rescue!

Comment: Also, indentation is your friend.

Comment: 5 to the 6th power is 15,625.  4 to the 15,625th power is already much, much, much  bigger than can be stored in an `int` or even a `long`.

Comment: That is going to be a pretty large number.

Comment: I ran this through an IDE printing the values of `i`. Then this happened: `...4611686018427387904
0`. Seem to have overflown a lot.

Comment: Don't let these people tell you it can't be done! You got 5^6 down already. For 4, `doubleBitShift(100)` 5^6 times. For 3, `result = result + singleBitShift(result)` 4^5^6 times. Then for 2, `bitshift(10)` 3^4^5^6 times. Don't try to solve this with code. Solve it with Math! Note that I don't expect this to actually run. You'll have to prove that your program is theoretically correct.

Comment: @John, the only way to solve with Math is by finding a similar representation such as `2^(3^(2^31250)))`. If that is what you mean then we can come to a understanding. Proposing someone to use bit shifting operations to solve a problem with giant numbers is not the way to go (I mean, as a Interviewer I would be happy with a proof that it can't be calculated anytime soon and would certainly discard someone that wrote a "correct" but unfeasible algorithm).

Comment: it could be a problem to be solved in a cluster, maybe you cannot do it in one computer, but what about several computers?

Comment: @Anthony In order to write a proof about an algorithm's complexity, you must first have an algorithm.

Comment: do you really intend to calculate the value? or do you merely hat do describe the algorithm?  i don^t think any file would be large enough to contain a text of that length... even if you had calculated the value, you wouldn't have a medium to write it down on ...

Answer (score 4):

4^(5^6) equals 4^15625, which is approximately 1,53*10^9407, a number which greatly exceeds the maximum value for the Long type, which is (2^64)-1.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 3):

These numbers are humongous. Really. 5^6 = 15625. Raise 4 to that power and you'll get enough digits as there are particles in the known Universe.

Your problem with 0 comes from the fact that 4 is 100 in binary. Multiply by 4 and you get 10000 in binary. Raise to a little more than that (max power 8, 16, maybe 32 if data types support it; talking in general) and you'll drop the single 1 bit you had out of the integer representation => 0.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you can choose the language. I advise you to implement this computation with Matlab or Octave:

```
2^3^4^5^6
```

prints the result you expect.

Comment: well,I am not familiar with either unfortunately. I was thinking of working this in Java ? This is also a popular interview question (becoming popular these days ) I guess. I have a few friends who were asked in companies like Monster and EMC. So I thought of working this on my own too. I am sure, there has to be some solution :)

Comment: You are right this is a good exercise. But I prefer give a faster method, because we cannot know your purpose or that of the futures visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The output is large enough and trips over to zero after crossing Long.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Actually, I guess that your teacher point here may be *do not try to do it*: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D%284%5E%285%5E6%29%29%29

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly HOLY FCUK! O_O

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's `BigInteger`, but I'm not sure whether such a huge number can be stored in memory.

Comment: BigInteger's pow() method takes an int parameter.. you'll have to reimplement pow(), too.

Comment: So implementing it with `mul` is not reasonable, 4^(5^6) will have more than 9000 digits, and iterating that much.... to just calculate 3^(4^(5^6))) would last forever.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is 2^(3^(4^(5^6))). Be careful with the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might use Math.pow(2, 3), to calculate 2 ^ 3. However since the output is that large, as shown in the following code, even double will return Infinity:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 2^(3^(4^(5^6)))
        System.out.println(Math.pow(2, Math.pow(3, Math.pow(4, Math.pow(5, 6)))));
    }

}
```

However you might use java.math.BigDecimal, which can handle this large integers. For this question I would propose python, were you could just write

```
2 ** (3 ** (4 ** (5 ** 6)))
```

EDIT:

Do you know that 4 ** (5 ** 6) already is

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6840260/

do you really want to calculate with this number in Java, which is not the fastest language for math problems?

Comment: this one is giving me Infinity in Java :)

Comment: I am not calculating by choice :) This one is asked by interviewers

Comment: @Happy: It's calculating since 7 minutes now. Perhaps Matlab is the better choice.

However even the linux command line calculator bc don't work for this problem: 2^(3^(4^(5^6))) 
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=18): exponent too large in raise

Comment: Internet, the point here is to know how large of a number it is on spot and plainly laugh on the interviewer face (I would hire you on spot). No use trying to calculate `3^([the mentioned number])`.

Comment: Quant, please stop the calculation, you aren't going anywhere with this :D. Also paste my link or something, we don't want people having to scroll through this beast.

Comment: I would never go to a company with such an idiot interviewer!

Comment: @Amir, actually this is a very clever question. I used something similar in the past (really large Fibonacci number that would be too big to calculate event using the closed formula and big decimals). A smart candidate is expect to spot the huge number and say that it will not be feasible to calculate it accurately even with the best known practices, and an exceptional one may even point out a way to get a good estimation (say, order of magnitude).

Comment: Well a good estimation for the running time would be interessting. I checked wiki and found (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) that multiplication can be done in O(n log n 2^log* n). So even squaring 4^(5^6)(which is not as far as big as 3^(number)) will take a lot of time to execute

Answer (score 0):

did you try this algorithm ? [Exponentation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: the question of dealing with Big Numbers still stands even if I use this algo